# Error with fromstring function from lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Trying to do

```
import lxml.etree

xml_str = """
<root>
<H4>

</H4>
<P>
Hong Kong, February 06, 2020 -- </P>
<P>
&bull; Testing data only
</P>
</root>
"""

utf8_parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
metadata_xml = lxml.etree.fromstring("""<root>""" + xml_str + """</root>""",
                                     parser=utf8_parser)
```

I am getting an error:

```
 File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1757, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1068, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 9
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'bull' not defined, line 9, column 7
```

Anybody know how I can get around this?

Comment: Use lxml's HTML parser instead of the XML parser. That isn't valid XML.

Comment: use &amp; in place of &

Answer (score 0):

As jordanm commented, use the HTML parser instead of the XML parser.

```py
import lxml.etree

xml_str = r"""
<root>
<H4>

</H4>
<P>
Hong Kong, February 06, 2020 -- </P>
<P>
&bull; Testing data only
</P>
</root>
"""

html_parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()

metadata_xml = lxml.etree.fromstring("""<root>""" + xml_str + """</root>""", 
                                     parser=html_parser)
```

If you insist on using the XML parser, you could unescape the `&bull;` character entity reference like so:

```py
import html

xml_str = html.unescape(xml_str)
```

Comment: What's your output when you try `print(metadata_xml)`?

Comment: It is `<Element html at 0x2ac33f2ae88>`. You probably want this: `lxml.etree.tostring(metadata_xml, encoding="unicode")`. Be sure to read the [documentation](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html)!